# How to groupby in pandas with json as value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My pandas DataFrame data:

```
     dat1 dat2 dat3
0    1    1    [{"gid": 1, "bs": "2", "_cc": "1"}]
1    1    1    [{"gid": 1, "bs": "2", "_cc": "1"}]
2    2    3    [{"gid": 3, "bs": "5", "_cc": "1"}]
```

I need to groupby the column dat1, my expected output should be:

```
     dat1 dat2 dat3
0    1    1    [{"gid": 1, "bs": "2", "_cc": "1"}]
1    2    3    [{"gid": 3, "bs": "5", "_cc": "1"}]
```

I used pandas dataframe as follow:

```
data = dataframedata   #dataframe data 
(out['dat1','dat2','dat3']).groupby([ 'dat1','dat2','dat3']).size().reset_index()
```

I get `keyerror at dat3`, please guide me to find the solution thanks in advance.

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates()` not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is `list`s are not hashable, so need convert them to strings:

```
data = df[~df['dat3'].astype(str).duplicated()] 
print (data)
   dat1  dat2                                 dat3
0     1     1  [{'gid': 1, 'bs': '2', '_cc': '1'}]
2     2     3  [{'gid': 3, 'bs': '5', '_cc': '1'}]
```

If want remove duplicates by multiple columns:

```
data = df[~df.assign(dat3= df['dat3'].astype(str)).duplicated(['dat1','dat2','dat3'])] 
print (data)
   dat1  dat2                                 dat3
0     1     1  [{'gid': 1, 'bs': '2', '_cc': '1'}]
2     2     3  [{'gid': 3, 'bs': '5', '_cc': '1'}]
```

Comment: df[~df['dat3'].astype(str).duplicated()] ... This works for me @jezrael ... Thank you

Comment: @selvakumar - Supper, it is better solution.